# How to stop receiving email failures for Google Apps Script: Email Scheduler for Gmail?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not tech savy here but I would appreciate a simple straight english language to tell me what I can do to stop receiving those emails that I get everyday.

Can anyone point me to the right direction with or without tutorial?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have been having this issue for ages and I think I just found out how to stop it. Basically the removal of the "Email Scheduler for GMail" script does not remove the trigger when the uninstall happens so we have to do it manually.

1. Go to [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) while logged into the account receiving the failure notifications.
2. Click "New script" on the upper left side
3. Go to "Edit" -> "All your triggers"
4. Click Okay with the generic name, it doesn't matter
5. Click the "X" next to the time based trigger for "Email Scheduler for GMail"

solution from https://ctrlq.org/docs/20474-summary-failures-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the email from 'apps-scripts-notifications@google.com' and is the format like this?

> Your script, "Script Name Here", has recently failed to finish successfully.
>   A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers
>   for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure
>   notifications, **click here**.
>
> The script is used by the document 'Document Name Here".

You can click on the notifications link in the email given by 'click here' and change/delete the trigger error notification.

For detailed documentation visit [the link here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#errors_in_triggers).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have clicked Click Here and it brings me to a blank page saying Forbidden Error 403.

and I clicked on the documentation you suggested and followed it. When I go into Google Apps Script I don't have any projects running and in Settings it says Google Apps Script API is off.

I am still getting those emails.

Birthe

Answer (score 0):

actually, I have the same error.  I had in the past but I'm not sure how I solved it.
so searching again for an answer.  Error: Authorization is required to perform that action. when I click here is the 403 error.

> Blockquote
>   our script, Monthly stats for Gmail, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

It happened after I changed the password, but I can't find this script anywhere in my settings so I can't change it. kinda strange.