# How to stop emails from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com, garbageCollectorViewer?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting lots of these emails:
"Your script, Eml Manager, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

Summary:

Error Message   Count
Authorization is required to perform that action.   49
"

I used the instruction in this link: [How to stop receiving email failures for Google Apps Script: Email Scheduler for Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731270/how-to-stop-receiving-email-failures-for-google-apps-script-email-scheduler-for)

Unfortunately, my triggers list is empty. What should I do? How can I stop those emails?

Thank you,
Ania.

Comment: Hello Anna, just so I understand: You have logged into the email that you used to create the script, you have visited the script editor and gone to Edit>All triggers and there you deleted every entry that appeared. **After** doing that, you still received another e-mail about your script being run. Is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like you have a simple trigger trying to do the job of an installable trigger.  Perhaps you have and extra onEdit() floating around in your code that you forgot about. Or one that your using to build a menu and also run some other function that requires user permissions.